# NiFi InvokeHttp JavaScript message

Tags: javascript, postman, apache-nifi

I'm trying to use InvokeHttp to do a POST request. The request has two arguments that are passing on body and the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. But I'm receiving the following response from the website

JavaScript is required. Please enable JavaScript.

I am able to do this request using Postman but in NiFi doesn't work

The response should be the download of a XLS File

Should I need to pass something specific about this?

[NiFi Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKYG9.png)

[updateAttribute configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L62UW.png)

[invokeHttp configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opJFj.png)

[invokeHttp configuration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqJud.png)

[postman execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYSRB.png)

[responseError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkDPK.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Your request might need a `accept` header set to `application/json`, can't be sure unless I know what kind of data the url returns

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I forgot to describe this. The response should be the download of a XLS File @VaibhavVishal

Comment: usually this error you have because of one of those headers is not correct: `accept` or `user-agent`. check exact values for those hesders in postman. and better to ask api developers when this error occurs.

Comment: Hello, @daggett. I used the same accept and user-agent from Postman but the response still complain about JavaScript

Comment: Please add screenshots and copy/paste of the flow, processor configuration, error output, and Postman execution so we can help you solve this.

Comment: Hello @Andy thanks for the reply. I added some screenshots. Thanks

Comment: Are you providing the cookie in NiFi? It appears your request headers in Postman include a cookie value.

Comment: No I'm not. Postman add automatically the cookie value. Is it possible to configure NiFi to do the same? @Andy

Comment: Yes, add it as an attribute on the incoming flowfile or a dynamic property on the `InvokeHTTP` processor.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a silly question but If I add an attribute in Update Attribute for example, what would be the value of this attribute? And about dynamic property I searched but couldn't find an example about that :/ @Andy

Comment: Any property that you explicitly add using the "*+*" in the top right of the processor configuration dialog is a _dynamic property_. The value of the attribute would be the `cookie` value in Postman: `JSESSIONID=...`. You may want to take a look at https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/getting-started.html to understand NiFi terminology.